# Authenticate HTML form with web server by jQuery

Tags: encryption, xss

I am building a simple web application.
I don't have the ability of using SSL to secure the communication with the client.

Right now the flow is:

**First time the user is registering:**

1) The user is choosing a user and a password (HTML form)

2) The password is being hashed by a hash function and a key (with concatenated salt) (jQuery)

3) The hash result is being sent to the server and stored in the DB

**In any login:**

1) In the welcome page - The password is being hashed and the result is being sent to the server

and being compered with the hash result from the the DB.
2) If the password is correct' a authentication token is being sent to the client and being 
stored in a cookie.

3) In every page the token is sent to the server and being validated.

** My Questions are: **

1) Is my way of encrypting the data is good or is it lack (comparing it to SSL)?

2) How can I prevent XSS (cross site scripting) - steeling the token from the user cookie and using to to retrieve data from the server without supplying user and password?

Answer (score 0):

> Is my way of encrypting the data is good or is it lack (comparing it to SSL)?

No. The hashed password is effectively the real password and is sent in the clear.

> How can I prevent XSS (cross site scripting) - steeling the token from the user cookie and using to to retrieve data from the server without supplying user and password?

With the usual mechanisms for protecting your site against XSS, i.e. sanitising / escaping all the data you output so scripts can't be injected from clients.